# ASP.NET Core and injecting IServiceProvider

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So, I've been reading about CQRS while deciding about architecture for my project and found [this](https://github.com/hlaueriksson/CommandQuery) library. It's not very complex or anything like that but one thing caught my eye: [here](https://github.com/hlaueriksson/CommandQuery/blob/fdd73104f9bb73f46de531ef3de2a91bc7f5bd4a/src/CommandQuery/ICommand.cs#L32) the `ISeviceProvider` is being injected and [here](https://github.com/hlaueriksson/CommandQuery/blob/fdd73104f9bb73f46de531ef3de2a91bc7f5bd4a/src/CommandQuery/ICommand.cs#L55) it is being used. So, my question: is it a good practice to build objects with service provider directly, meaning without the **injecting**? If not which would be the correct way to build objects if the type of object will be known only in runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `IServiceProvider` is basically the only option for DI (e.g. via `RequestServices` in MVC components) if you only know the type at run-time.

Constructor injection is only viable if you already know the type at compile-time, because you must specify the type of the object in the constructor.

Depending on the need, you can also register an implementation factory in `ConfigureServices()`, and give out different instances of some interface depending on runtime information.

EDIT: An example of an implementation factory in ASP.NET Core:

```
services.AddTransient<IDataService, DataService>((ctx) =>
{
    IOtherService svc = ctx.GetService<IOtherService>();
    //IOtherService svc = ctx.GetRequiredService<IOtherService>();
    return new DataService(svc);
});
```

Here `DataService` depends on `IOtherService`, so it gets it from the service provider with `GetService<T>()`. You can use `GetRequiredService<T>()` to enforce the requirement.

Comment: agree, but factory won't let you inject anything into objects you build unless you manually create dependency but then you loose the advantage of dependency injection built-in framework

Comment: True, though in the factory you can request dependencies from the container so it's not entirely manual.

Comment: what do you mean? could you provide an example for that? are you talking that factory receives the service provider or am I missing somethig?

Comment: Added an example :)

Answer (score 3):

> is it a good practice to build objects with service provider directly, meaning without the injecting?

It depends. Injecting a generic resolver into a class instead of specific dependencies is a pattern generally referred to as [Service Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) and it is considered to be [an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Whether or not the use of this `IServiceProvider` is an implementation of the Service Locator anti-pattern however, depends on how it is used, as explained [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/):

> A DI container encapsulated in a [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) is not a Service Locator - it's an infrastructure component.

We can consider this `CommandProcessor` to be a piece of infrastructure, as long as it is "encapsulated in a Composition Root".

Comment: but `Only applications should have Composition Roots. Libraries and frameworks shouldn't`

Comment: @arthur.borisow: that's correct. the `CommandProcessor` should be part of the start up project. You should certainly not place the `ICommand` and `ICommandHandler<T>` abstractions and `CommandProcessor` implementation in the same project.